# Count Repeated Values in Json String and store value and label in another String

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, jsonp

I need to count the number of repeating items in the json array , and show the repeating items as single item and count should be shown how many tiems it has repeated..

please check the below code and Output so that you can understand:

```
[{
    "Name": "Jacob",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "City": "Newyork",
    "State": "Newyork"
}, {
    "Name": "Mason",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "State": "California"
}, {
    "Name": "Ethan",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "City": "Chicago",
    "State": "Illinois"
}, {
    "Name": "Noah",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "City": "Newyork",
    "State": "NewYork"
}, {
    "Name": "Sophia",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "State": "California"
}, {
    "Name": "Emma",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "State": "California"
}, {
    "Name": "Isabella",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Chicago",
    "State": "Illinois"
}, {
    "Name": "Olivia",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Chicago",
    "State": "Illinois"
}, {
    "Name": "Elizabeth",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Newyork",
    "State": "Newyork"
}, {
    "Name": "zoey",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "City": "Newyork",
    "State": "Newyork"
}]
```

The desired output from json is

```
Newyork : 4Times,
```

chicago:3 times,

Please find the fiddle :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/vamsikrishna981/dMrNv/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/RHYFC/

See LONG VERSION and SHORT VERSION on fiddle

Javascript

```
var result = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var item in data[i]){
        if(!result[item]){
            result[item] = {};
        }

        if(!result[item][data[i][item]]){
            result[item][data[i][item]] = 0;
        }

        result[item][data[i][item]]++;
    }
}
```